# Adding user meta values to Wordpress admin emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email

When a new user registers on our website, they are required to fill out their company information.  This information is stored in the _usermeta table with the meta_key 'company'.

All I want to do is include this information in the notification email that Wordpress sends to the site administrator.  I have had some luck manipulating pluggables.php (where the default email code is located), but I can't get any meta values to send in the email.

Here is my current code:

```
function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plaintext_pass = '') {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id );
    $company = $user_meta['company'][0];

// The blogname option is escaped with esc_html on the way into the database in sanitize_option
// we want to reverse this for the plain text arena of emails.
$blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

$message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your site %s:'), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('Name: %s'), $user->display_name) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user->user_email) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('Company: %s'), $company) . "\r\n";

@wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), $blogname), $message);
```

The code outputs:

New user registration on your site mywebsite

Name: firstname lastname

E-mail: email@example.com

Company:

I have included get_user_meta() and get_metadata() but the value is always blank.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you check that `company` is in there in database for a sp. user or not? It might be that while users are registering the `company` meta is not being inserted into database.

Comment: I checked this... for each id, a meta_key is generated as 'company' and a meta_value is added based on their submission e.g. 'McDonalds'

Comment: ok, now use `die();` before `wp_mail` and print `get_user_meta( $user_id )` and check it is returning `company` or not.

Comment: you might not be pulling the data properly, 
Just pull the company key directly ```$company = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'company', true);```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... pulling the company key directly had the same result and print get_user_meta( $user_id ) returned an empty value for company :/

Comment: @RaunakGupta here is the print Array ( [nickname] => Array ( [0] => testpeople@test.com ) [first_name] => Array ( [0] => test ) [last_name] => Array ( [0] => people ) [description] => Array ( [0] => ) [rich_editing] => Array ( [0] => true ) [comment_shortcuts] => Array ( [0] => false ) [admin_color] => Array ( [0] => fresh ) [use_ssl] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [show_admin_bar_front] => Array ( [0] => true ) [wpad_capabilities] => Array ( [0] => a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;} ) [wpad_user_level] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )

Comment: @fulltimehatr: You array did't have `company` key as expected. I dont know what might be the issue, But manually added a `company` to admin user through `phpmyadmin` and used `echo get_user_meta( 1, 'company', true);` I got the result. you might be having some permission issue from plugin or a specific user might not have that attribute.

Comment: @RaunakGupta thanks for steering me in that direction. The plugin I use is called profilepress and it adds multiple rows to the meta table after the above array. It seems like it sends the email THEN adds the "custom" values to the table. Odd. I may try digging around the code to see if I can prioritize these extra values.

Comment: @fulltimehatr: you are welcome. cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  The plugin I use to create new users (profile press) was posting the new user, triggering wp_new_user_notification, THEN adding custom values to the meta table.  I moved the meta table function above wp_new_user_notification and the data is transferring as expected.  Should anyone else run into this issue, here is how to solve it:

In wp-includes/pluggable.php, the following works as expected:

```
$company = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'company', true ); 
$message .= sprintf(__('Company: %s'), $company) . "\r\n";
```

As for profile press, navigate to wp-content/plugins/profilepress/classes/class-registration-form-auth.php and put:

```
// register custom profile field
if ( ! is_wp_error($user_id)) {
.
//truncated
.
            do_action('pp_after_custom_field_update', $key, $value, $user_id, 'registration');
        }
    }
```

above:

```
    if (is_int($user_id) && 'enable' == $new_user_notification) {
        wp_new_user_notification($user_id, null, 'admin');
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone else who has similar issues. Special thanks to @RaunakGupta for pointing me in the direction and credit to profile press for their code.